# SQL Server requests shared lock on a page in a statement with nolock hint

Tags: sql-server, indexing, locking, deadlock, nolock

Subj.

Look at the deadlock graph and the statement below. Why does it happen?

```
declare @SomeValue bigint = 12345      

select <SOME FIELDS>
from [HealthEvent].[StateMachineInstanceEventTypeQueue] nolock  
where SomeField = @SomeValue
order by id desc
```

The table doesn't have an index on SomeField

See the deadlock graph:
http://i58.tinypic.com/rbfmex.jpg

Comment: This doesn't answer the question but did you consider snapshot isolation? That can solve a ton of concurrency problems.

Comment: There is no matter. I just want to get a reasonable answer why does it happen. It seems confusing to me.

Comment: That's not a `NOLOCK` hint in your query.  You are using it as an alias.

Comment: @DMason ha! How funny.

Comment: Try something like `SELECT <columns>
FROM dbo.YourTable
WITH (NOLOCK)`

Comment: You could just remove the NOLOCK hint. If missing and/or duplicate information is acceptable then that is fine but if accuracy is important that hint will not suffice.